# How can I solve Exercise 3 Programming in C, Stephen Kochan - Chapter 11

Tags: c

I want to know what the sentence "Think about setting up a special structure to point to the beginning of the list" means. Does it mean that he wants in the exercise to create a new structure pointing to the beginning of the beginning of the list, instead of the structure that was used in the exercise to make the list? Or does he mean to make a dummy structure of the same structure that was created in exercise 2? I made the program; it looks like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct entry
{
    int value;
    struct entry *next;
};

struct entry *head, n1, n2, n3, n4, temp;

void insertentry (struct entry *newEntry/*= temp*/, struct entry *EntryNo/*=head*/ )
{
    newEntry->next = EntryNo->next;
    EntryNo->next = newEntry;
}

int main()
{
    void insertentry (struct entry *newEntry, struct entry *EntryNo );

    head     = &n1;
    n1.value = 100;
    n1.next  = &n2;
    n2.value = 200;
    n2.next  = &n3;
    n3.value = 300;
    n3.next  = (struct entry *) 0;
    n4.value = 340;
    printf("the value before the new entry\n");
    while(head != (struct entry *) 0) {
        printf("%i\n", head->value);
        head = head->next;
    }

    head      = &temp;
    temp.next = &n1;
    insertentry(&n4, &temp.next);
    printf("the value after the new entry\n");
    while(head != (struct entry *) 0) {
        printf("%i\n", head->value);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

When I ran the program, this is what appeared (exactly):

```
the value before the new entry
100
200
300
the value after the new entry
340
0
100
200
300
```

I made a dummy structure called "temp" to point to the beginning of the list, 
but when the program started to run the value in the dummy structure appeared. What exactly should I do? Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. It would help immensely to post the text of the exercise as most people will not have a copy of the book.

Comment: `insertentry(&n4,&temp.next);` type mismatch.

Comment: The declaration of `insertentry` inside `main` is unnecessary. It's already visible, because the definition precedes the definition of `main`. Even if that weren't the case, it's rarely a good idea to declare functions inside function definitions.

Comment: The list head is currently just `struct entry *head`. The author probably encourages to put it into an appropriate struct instead of using it directly e.g. `struct List { struct entry *head; }`. Next step could be to put all list management in dedicated functions which always get at least a `struct List` parameter (or `struct List*`). At the first glance, this seems to be nothing else than extra effort. Later you will recognize, that this is the "1st step towards modular and object oriented programming" - encapsulating the data together with functions which are processing it (on lowest level).

Comment: I had basically the same thought as Scheff, I'm pretty sure thats what the exercise is about. It will be specially helpful when modifying (add, remove) the beginning of the list.